# Updating Table Rows with another table data

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I have two tables I am trying to update table A data with table B. Table A (ids) has 100 rows (based on a condition) and I want to replace those ids with table B(ids).

## Table A

- abc
- def
- klm
- ijk

## Table B

- abc1234
- pknm
- lokimh
- 2546njnh

can you please provide me the SQL to replace these ids form table B to table A
there are 100 rows which i need to update from table B to table A.

```
Cursor trans 
select id 
from table B 
where rownnum <=100 

cursor user 
select id 
from table A
```

Comment: Based on what condition? Please, be more specific and provide more details...

Answer (score 0):

```
update tab_a set colname =
(select colname from tab_b where -- condition, use the condition you are referring to )
```